# Edit Dictionary String values in a .plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, dictionary, plist

I know this must be very simple. But I can't figure it out.
I have a Help.plist file, it has a key and then a dictionary with string values.

Where is the content for these dictionarys generally held.

When I search the string value in XCODE it does not come up.

This is leading me to believe it in the /documents/ section of the app. Should I use something like text edit to edit the value?

Note : I know the .plist file is a file of XML type. I do not want to edit this. I want to edit the contents of the dictionary.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the dictionary for editing

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Help" withExtension:@"plist"]] mutableCopy];
```

Then you can edit it with the functions in [`NSMutableDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/)...

I don't think you can edit the contents of a file in your app's resources, so you may want to save it to the Documents folder after editing...